# ActionView::Template::Error (no implicit conversion of nil into String)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've never gotten an error like this before, and not sure how to get rid of it.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (no implicit conversion of nil into String)
...
24: <p>Genre:<%= link_to @movie.genre, "movies?genre=" + @movie.genre.to_s %></p>
....
app/views/movies/show.html.erb:24:in `+'
```

Comment: Is `@movie` is a collection? I guess `@movie` is nil.

Comment: No it's not, just an object (I think that's what it's called...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be able to handle possible nil values. Change your code to this :

```
<p>Genre:<%= link_to @movie.try(:genre), "movies?genre=" + @movie.try(:genre) %></p>
```

Since the entire link depends on having a genre, you could even do this :

```
<p>Genre:<%= link_to @movie.try(:genre), "movies?genre=" + @movie.try(:genre) if @movie.genre %></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably `@movie.genre` is nil.

So, when you try to `@movie.genre.to_s` you are actually doing this:

```
nil.to_s
```

Which cannot be done.

So you should, do something like:

```
<% if @movie && @movie.genre %>
  <p>Genre:<%= link_to @movie.genre, "movies?genre=" + @movie.genre.to_s %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It had the error before I put `.to_s` and I thought that would fix it, but it did not.